# Vue JS bind class to child of every even element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I dynamically add a class (`timelineEven`) to list the element on every even `ul`? I was able to add the `timeline_inverted_parent` class to every other `ul` parent element with:

```
v-bind:class="{'timeline_inverted_parent': index % 2 }">
```

Just not sure how I would pass that to a child `li` of every even instance of `ul` containing `timeline_inverted_parent` class.

```html
<invoices-campaign
v-for="(invoicesCampaign, index) in invoicesCampaigns"
v-bind:invoices-campaign="invoicesCampaign"
v-bind:key="invoicesCampaign.id"
v-bind:class="{'timeline_inverted_parent': index % 2 }">
</invoices-campaign>

<script type="text/x-template" id="invoices-campaign">
    <ul class="timeline">
        <li></li>
```

Comment: Why do you need to set that class on the `li`? If this is for styling purposes, just use a selector like `.timeline_inverted_parent > li`.

Comment: there's an existing css already in place styling timelineEven as well as other items across the app. Don't necessarily need the class timeline_inverted_parent on ul, just need to add 'timelineEven' to the li child of every other ul instance

Comment: You can't set that class on a child element of the component from the outside, instead you would have to do so via a prop.

Comment: thanks, I'll try to find something on that. Not well experienced with Vuejs. appreciate your input

Answer (score 0):

In `invoices-campaign`, create a Boolean prop (named `invertedParent`) 1️⃣ that's used in a [class binding](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html#Object-Syntax) 2️⃣ for `timelineEven` on the even instances of `li`:

```html
<template>
  <ul class="timeline">
    <li v-for="(item, i) in invoicesCampaign.items"
        :class="{ timelineEven: invertedParent && i % 2 === 0 }"> 2️⃣
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'invoices-campaign',
  props: {
    invertedParent: Boolean, 1️⃣
    invoicesCampaign: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

In the consumer, you would set `invertedParent` with the `index` as you were doing before:

```html
<invoices-campaign v-bind:invertedParent="index % 2">
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/conditional-style-binding-pux4s?file=/src/components/InvoicesCampaign.vue:114-177)